# MySQL will not start

Tags: apt, mysql

Well, I seem to have totally broken MySQL, possibly through a combination of recently trying to upgrade mysql workbench, which needed me to install some mysql-apt-config package, which broke my usual upgrades with some dialog that appeared on apt-get upgrade which I was unable to quit out of, so I uninstalled mysql-apt-config.

Now I come to use my local mysql server (for the first time in a while), find it's failing to start (in an endless loop - this message repeated: https://gist.github.com/asgrim/5874f73783954c22d217) with no indication of what the error is.

So I run `sudo mysqld` on cli, that complains about being unable to read errmsg.sys (which exists at this point) so I think maybe it's corrupt, I `apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client` and re-install them, and now errmsg.sys is vanished, and that's me right now :)

Current status:

```
$ sudo mysqld
150312 10:09:57 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150312 10:09:57 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
$ ls -l /usr/local/mysql/share/english/errmsg.sys
ls: cannot access /usr/local/mysql/share/english/errmsg.sys: No such file or directory
$ ls -l /usr/share/errmsg.sys
ls: cannot access /usr/share/errmsg.sys: No such file or directory
$ ls -l /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys
ls: cannot access /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys: No such file or directory
```

A `locate errmsg.sys` indicates nothing.

Comment: It's a binary file, from mysql-server-core-5.5 on my system. Try reinstalling that one?

Comment: That's it! I can't begin to thank you. If you add this up as an answer I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing errmsg.sys should be there.

It's a binary file, from [`mysql-server-core-5.5`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mysql-server-core-5.5/filelist) on my system.

Try reinstalling that one?