# Error when reinstalling mysql-server "postinst: line 102: mysqld: command not found"

Tags: 18.04, package-management, mysql

I removed mysql-server because I set it up incorrectly. When I try to install it now I get this error:

```
matthew@matthewserver:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Ign:4 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages 
[387 kB]
Hit:6 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release
Fetched 559 kB in 1s (862 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
matthew@matthewserver:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 102: mysqld: command not found
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have no idea what this means. How do I go about installing it?

Comment: when you make new installing `mysql-server-5.7` make sure your configure it correctly, if it not correctly try `sudo dpkg-configure mysql-server-5.7` and follow that instruction.

Comment: the output said "Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server" , 0ohh! you have two package of mysql, please choose one less.

Comment: sorry sir, i do not understand what you want me to do

Comment: try to type `sudo dpkg-configure mysql-server-5.7`. you have two package of mysql, please choose one!.

Comment: i get `sudo: dpkg-configure: command not found`

Comment: sorry mistakenly written, try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7`

Comment: i got `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.7 is broken or not fully installed
`

Comment: you need completly remove mysql-server-5.7 and mysql-server package, try to run `sudo apt-get purge --remove mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server && sudo apt-get autoremove` and update your apt, and try to reinstall `mysql-server-5.7`.

Comment: when i try to install it again it says `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: what the output of `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7 | pastebinit` and make sure you have `pastebinit` package, and then please share the link of pastebinit.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yPMyFeBh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL will not start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595882/mysql-will-not-start)

Comment: I note that the error begins when MySQL is unable to start.  Can you open a terminal window and try to start the server by hand, so see what error it throws?  The outputs of `systemctl status mysql` and `sudo systemctl start mysql` would be good to have.  You may also be able to find info in `journalctl -b | grep -i sql`.  If you could please, append some of this information to your question?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -r mysql-client-5.7
sudo dpkg -r mysql-server-5.7
sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient20:i386
sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient20:amd64
sudo dpkg -r libmysqlclient18:amd64
sudo dpkg -r mysql-common
sudo dpkg -r mysql 
sudo apt-get install mysql mysql-client* mysql-server*
```

Comment: Explain why you think this might be the answer please.